# SQL Server client statistics wait on server reply vs server side execution

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm running SQL query through SQL Management studio with both client statistics and "Set Statistics Time", query I run is:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

Set statistics time reports:
[image: statistics time]

While client statistics reports:
[image: clients statistics]

It means that "Wait time on server replies" is **344ms** higher than what is reported as server execution time.

How can I investigate where those additional seconds come from? Does "Wait time on server replies" mean time until server sending the data or arrival on the client side?

Comment: Is there 172ms latency between your SSMS client and the remote SQL Server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning 85ms reported from ping to the database server

Comment: @MartinSmith With query like that SSMS does not display the execution plan despite selecting it in options

Comment: Ah sorry I completely missed that you were just running a `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'` statement!

Comment: On that basis 344ms is four packets, so that squares with probably a `PRELOGIN` and `LOGIN` packets, plus `RPC` and `DONE` packets. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/58886b79-ec75-42f3-bd7b-e32f327366b6 I must say, 85ms is long for a database server, you should consider moving the server closer to the client.